# Enabling Email Notifications for Application Creation Workflow

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm able to configure workflows for Application Creation. I tried to configure email notifications to the Admin user when a new Application creation so that the Admin receive a new email message for approval process.

Is it possible to configure email notifications for workflows - particularly for Application Creation workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box capability to send email notifications to approvers or Admins when a new workflow item is created. This feature is not available, at least for now. The way the current workflow architecture works is it uses task-based approach and depends on the database, hense it is not possible to send automatic emails out.

For more information, please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/advanced-topics/adding-an-application-creation-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom Workflow extension by extending `WorkflowExecutor` class. You can refer to [this class](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/a74179a498ad4c806a0baeef792f137b9495428d/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/workflow/ApplicationCreationApprovalWorkflowExecutor.java#L50). This is the default implementation, you can customize the class to send an Email notification when an Application is created and add the customized class when configuring the Workflow. [This](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-workflows/configuring-http-redirection-for-workflows/#writing-the-custom-workflow-executor) document has more details on writing a custom workflow executor.

Comment: I guess as per @Joy Rathnayake, there is no out-of-the-box way of doing this, right? We will have to write custom code and get it done?